# /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__.py' in '/' when using subprocess.call

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script to do some admin functionality which involves running several other python scripts.

A snipet of my code looks like this:

```
import subprocess

PYTHON_BIN_DIR = '/usr/bin/python'
SCRIPTS_DIR = '/some/path'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dateparam = "05-Jan-2012"
    command = [PYTHON_BIN_DIR]
    command.extend(SCRIPTS_DIR + "/myfile1.py")
    strparams = " --param1={0} ".format(123)
    command.extend(strparams)
    command.extend(dateparam)

    retcode = subprocess.call(command)

    if retcode != 0:
        # do something
        pass
    else:
        # do something else
        pass
```

All the scripts I'm calling are using the `if __name__ == ""__main__""` check/test. So what's causing the error?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `append` instead of `extend`?

Comment: @larsmans: Doh!. Stupid mistake on my part. Hanging my head in shame here ...

Comment: @larsmans: as an aside though, although correcting the code as you pointed out has got rid of the error in the title, the argparse module does not seem to recognise the parameters being passed to the process - I'm getting this error: scriptname.py: error: unrecognized arguments:  --param1=123   --date=05-Jan-2012  Any idea why?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Have you actually tried calling that script with those arguments manually?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: that's a feature/bug of your other script, I guess.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, that was the first thing I checked. The called scripts run fine when I pass the same parameters to them at the console. Infact, I copied the parameters printed to the console in the error message and run them manually - the "child" script run without any errors when the same parameters are fed it on the command line.

Comment: *offtopic alert* I prefer using `def main():\n *your_code_here*\n if __name__ == ""__main__""\n main()`. (Hope you get the idea.) This way you can easily call your main function from other script or C program if embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments you should use `append` instead of `extend`. I think your other problem is you've included spaces in your argument. I would split up each parameter, i.e. `--param1=123`:

```
import subprocess
import os.path

PYTHON_BIN_DIR = '/usr/bin/python'
SCRIPTS_DIR = '/some/path'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dateparam = "05-Jan-2012"
    command = [PYTHON_BIN_DIR, os.path.join(SCRIPTS_DIR, 'myfile1.py'),
               '--param1', 123, '--date', dateparam]

    retcode = subprocess.call(command)

    if retcode != 0:
        # do something
        pass
    else:
        # do something else
        pass
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I printed out sys.argv and saw that the strings had leading spaces. Problem solved.